# RequireJS + Angular Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module helloWorld

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I'm using requirejs and angularJS to build a simple app, however I keep getting this error every time, I've tried bootstraping angular from js(still on the code to be seen), change deps, requiring angular on app.js, but none worked. Can someone help me?

main.js

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: './lib/jquery/jquery.min',
        angular: './lib/angular/angular',
        bootstrap: './lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min',
        app: './app/app',
        custom: './lib/custom/custom'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            'exports': 'angular'
        },
        'jquery': {
            'exports': 'jquery'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'app': {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        'custom': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});

define(['require', 'jquery', 'angular', 'bootstrap', 'app', 'custom'],
    require(['require', 'jquery'], function (require, $) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        require(
                ['angular', 'app', 'custom', 'bootstrap']
            , function (angular, document) {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['helloWorld']);
            });
    });
}));
```

app.js

```
angular.module("helloWorld", []);
angular.module("helloWorld").controller("helloWorldCtrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.message = "Hello World!";
});
```

index.html

```
<html ng-app="helloWorld">
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script data-main="main" src="lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="helloWorldCtrl">
        {{message}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error message:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module helloWorld due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'helloWorld' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/nomod?p0=helloWorld
minErr/<@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:68:12
module/<@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:2075:17
ensure@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:1999:38
module@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:2073:14
loadModules/<@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:4608:22
forEach@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:321:11
loadModules@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:4592:5
createInjector@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:4514:19
bootstrap/doBootstrap@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:1751:20
bootstrap@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:1772:12
angularInit@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:1657:5
@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:31468:5
b.Callbacks/c@http://localhost:8000/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:7852
b.Callbacks/p.add@http://localhost:8000/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:8167
b.prototype.ready@http://localhost:8000/lib/jquery/jquery.min.js:3:2054
@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:31467:3
@http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.js:6:2

http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=helloWorld&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20Module%20'helloWorld'%20is%20not%20available!%20You%20either%20misspelled%20the%20module%20name%20or%20forgot%20to%20load%20it.%20If%20registering%20a%20module%20ensure%20that%20you%20specify%20the%20dependencies%20as%20the%20second%20argument.%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.7%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3DhelloWorld%0AminErr%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A68%3A12%0Amodule%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A2075%3A17%0Aensure%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1999%3A38%0Amodule%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A2073%3A14%0AloadModules%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4608%3A22%0AforEach%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A321%3A11%0AloadModules%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4592%3A5%0AcreateInjector%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A4514%3A19%0Abootstrap%2FdoBootstrap%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1751%3A20%0Abootstrap%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1772%3A12%0AangularInit%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A1657%3A5%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A31468%3A5%0Ab.Callbacks%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.min.js%3A3%3A7852%0Ab.Callbacks%2Fp.add%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.min.js%3A3%3A8167%0Ab.prototype.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fjquery%2Fjquery.min.js%3A3%3A2054%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A31467%3A3%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Flib%2Fangular%2Fangular.js%3A6%3A2%0A
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is, before bootstrapping helloWorld module you will have to make sure that it is created and available. It seems that when application got bootstrapped that time helloWorld module was not available.

Try the below code:

### main.js

```
    requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: './lib/jquery/jquery.min',
        angular: './lib/angular/angular',
        bootstrap: './lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min',
        app: './app/app',
        custom: './lib/custom/custom'
    },
    shim: {
        'angular': {
            'exports': 'angular'
        },
        'jquery': {
            'exports': 'jquery'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        'app': {
            deps: ['angular']
        },
        'custom': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});

require(['app'], function (app) {
});
```

### app.js

```
define(['angular'], function (angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('helloWorld', [])
  .controller("helloWorldCtrl", function ($scope) {
      $scope.message = "Hello World!";
  });

  angular.bootstrap(document, ['helloWorld']);
});
```

### index.html

```
<html >
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <script data-main="main" src="lib/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body >
    <div ng-controller="helloWorldCtrl">
        {{message}}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It should work!

Comment: Updated the code with bit of code optimization. This is working piece and I believe will help you to resolve your issues.